# Merge Elements (XML) With Same ID to txt file using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a task where I need to loop through an XML document and merge elements/nodes with the same ID. The output should be a csv file (for further processing) where each line have a fixed length. Based on the values of the nodes, that value needs to be placed at a certain location in the output.

Here is a **sample of the XML**:

```
<root>
    <User>
        <UserID>55555</UserID>
        <Value>Active</Value>
    </User>
    <User>
        <UserID>55555</UserID>
        <Value>Admin</Value>
    </User>
    <User>
        <UserID>55555</UserID>
        <Value>Eligible</Value>
    </User>
    <User>
        <UserID>123456</UserID>
        <Value>Active</Value>
    </User>
</root>
```

My **desired output** would be:

```
User ID, Active, Admin, Eligible
55555, Y, Y, Y,
123456, Y, N, N,
```

NOTE the values are ALWAYS THE SAME (Active, Admin & Eligible), but Users can have different amount of values like in the example.

Currently this is what I got:

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <Header>
            <xsl:text>User ID</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
            
            <xsl:text>Active</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
            
            <xsl:text>Admin</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
            
            <xsl:text>Eligible</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </Header>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="User" group-by="UserID"> 
                
                <!-- User ID -->
                <xsl:value-of select="UserID"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
                
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
                
                <xsl:value-of select="$lineFeed"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

This group and selects the correct elements, but then I need to place them under the correct headers (like axample with desired output).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is difficult to understand. Are you asking "James" and "New York" are just indicators that there is a value in the corresponding column? If so, what is the indicator for the Last Name column? Also, you say that the "output should be a csv file" but then you say " where each line have a fixed length". And your stylesheet seems to be producing a tab-separated file (with an XML header!). Those are three (or four) different things.

Comment: This is just examples. Properly not the best way to show it by using "Name" "Lastname" & "City". The idea is that the fields that should go under these headers always have the same value. So if the <Value>James</Value> Then this should go under Name etc. Indicator for "Lastname" would be <Value>Peterson</Value>. 

I changed the name of the variable to reflect the comma and not wrongly tab as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly (very big if!), you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>User ID, Active, Admin, Eligible&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- rows -->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="User" group-by="UserID"> 
        <!-- User ID -->
        <xsl:value-of select="UserID"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <!-- Active -->
        <xsl:value-of select="if (current-group()/Value[.='Active']) then 'Y' else'N'"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <!-- Admin -->
        <xsl:value-of select="if (current-group()/Value[.='Admin']) then 'Y' else'N'"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <!-- Eligible -->
        <xsl:value-of select="if (current-group()/Value[.='Eligible']) then 'Y' else'N'"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or more compactly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>User ID, Active, Admin, Eligible&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- rows -->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="User" group-by="UserID"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="UserID, for $t in ('Active', 'Admin', 'Eligible') return if (current-group()/Value[.=$t]) then 'Y' else 'N'" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result is slightly different from the one you posted: there is no trailing comma in each record.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Michael. This is excatly what I was looking for! I see you noted I edited the question to give more clarity and that you adjusted the answer.